# How much detail needs to go into my campaign before it starts?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development, homebrew, campaign

I'm designing a homebrew campaign for me and my friends, where I'll DM. I've decided basic things and written down basic notes of important things I want to happen, etc.

These are only scattered notes, and not at all structured or detailed.

The campaign is going to be open, allowing 5 or 6 different options of what the party needs to do/go at the start and they can be done in any order. I also want it to be possible for them to partly shape the story by their actions rather than force them along a path, which is a reason I don't want my notes to be overly detailed because they could no longer be useful depending on what the party does.

As for my DM experience I'm still fairly new, only making some basic, simple adventures back in 4th Edition and not much in 5th. I've got the grasp on how to do it, just not how deep to go into it.

So my question:
How detailed and specific should my notes be before I'm ready to start the adventure?

Do I write grand descriptions about the hallway down to read word for word or just list features about it?

Do I flesh out important NPC's just enough to do what they are in the campaign for or create a character with deep personality even if they won't be in the adventure for a long time?

Etc.

Comment: D&D 5e (updated tags)

Comment: I think it might also be useful for answerers to have a little detail about *you*, the GM. Are you new to GMing? Old hand at GMing but new to 5e? Something else?